# Sitemap generation error

Tags: magento-1.8, sitemaps

In my magento app, google sitemap generation frequency is set to daily. For the last 4 weeks, I see email saying the following error:
Sitemap generate warnings: dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Is there anybody who has any idea about this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks you all for your contributions. I did everything like permission settings. I did not make it 777 but the permission is set to website owner etc. Clearing cache, flushing redis cache etc and now i do not see the sitemap generation error for the last 7 days. So, it was a complete workaround although I am not sure what exactly fixed the issue. However, the described steps helped me to get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's not your case, but I hope my post can be helpful.
Some people say that they were faced with such error after some module installation. One of examples is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545546/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract

Maybe this error doesn't refers to sitemap generation and you are getting this error and further executing is stopped. Try to disable last installed extensions if it is possible

Other people tells that problem refers to permissions. Try to set recommended permissions. Clear cache.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801225/how-to-solve-magento-error-dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-ad

[Error 500 & dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/error-500-dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract)